# OPC UA Implement subscription mechanism

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, publish-subscribe, opc, opc-ua

I'm having trouble with OPC UA Subscriptions and Notifications. I want to subscribe server data. So I defined a monitoredItem list to capture the notification.

```
var list = new List<MonitoredItem> {
        new MonitoredItem(subscription.DefaultItem) { DisplayName = "Speed", StartNodeId = "ns=2;i=4"},
    };
Debug.Log(list[0].StartNodeId);
list.ForEach(i => i.Notification += OnNotification);
subscription.AddItems(list);
list.ForEach(i =>  Debug.Log(i.Subscription.Id));

Debug.Log("Add the subscription to the session.");
subscription.PublishingEnabled = true;
session.AddSubscription(subscription);
subscription.Create();
```

When ever it get new notification, it suppose to call the OnNotification deligate. But it my case the OnNotification is never be called.

```
private static void OnNotification(MonitoredItem item, MonitoredItemNotificationEventArgs e)
{
        Debug.Log("OnNotification");
        foreach (var value in item.DequeueValues())
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}", item.DisplayName, value.Value, value.SourceTimestamp, value.StatusCode);
        }
}
```

How can I implement subscription mechanism in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the subscription to your session:

```
session.AddSubscription(subscription)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have already added that **session.AddSubscription(subscription)**. Could you check the edit, please?
I also create the subscription **subscription.Create();**

But it doesn't make cane change.